# Django-Haystack elasticsearch config in cloud 9

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack, cloud9-ide

I'm trying to install `django-haystack` in my django project which I'm working on in the Cloud 9 online IDE. The documentation for `django-haystack` says to add this configuration to `settings.py`:

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine',
        'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/',
        'INDEX_NAME': 'haystack',
    },
}
```

But trying to run `./manage.py rebuild_index` results in an error: "Connection Refused".

If I try changing the URL value to `http://myproject-username.c9users.io:9200/` I also get an error: "ConnectTimeoutError".

Does anyone know what the correct configuration would be, or if I'm missing a step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud9 requires you to run apps on port `8080`, `8081`, or `8082`.

If you use `8080`, you can access your app from `https://myproject-username.c9users.io`. If you use the other two ports then you'll access it from `https://myproject-username.c9users.io:8081` or `https://myproject-username.c9users.io:8082`.

Find your `elasticsearch.yml` configuration file, and in the Network section uncomment `http.port` and set the value to one of the allowed ports (probably `8081` or `8082` if your main app is running on `8080`).

Comment: So I would have to change the port that haystack is using?

Comment: Yes, change your port to 8080 and then use https://myproject-username.c9users.io to access it.